# Understanding FragmentManager.getFragments() after detach because of "Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, fragment-lifecycle

I faced a problem debugging a code and the problem is that based on [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#getFragments()):

> public List getFragments ()
>
> Get a `list` of all fragments that are currently added to the
>   `FragmentManager`. This may include those that are hidden as well as
>   those that are shown. This will not include any `fragments` only in the
>   back stack, or fragments that are detached or removed.

when a `fragment` is detached it shouldn't be included in the returned list but by running this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentDetached(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, @NonNull Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentDetached(fm, f);
                Log.e("DetachDetected", f.getTag() + " Detached");
            }
        },false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        List<Fragment> lf = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        Log.e("ActivityOnCreate" , "Content hasn't been set yet");
        Log.e("ListInfo" , "Fragment list size is:" + lf.size());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("ActivityOnCreate" , "Content has been set");
        lf = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        Log.e("ListInfo" , "Fragment list size is:" + lf.size());

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.f_container, myFragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.e("ActivityInfo" , "Initiating MainActivity.onStart");
        super.onStart();
        List<Fragment> lf = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        Log.e("ListInfo" , "Fragment list size is:" + lf.size());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("ActivityInfo" , "Initiating MainActivity.onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**and changing the orientation, in the log I get:**

```
2020-04-19 04:02:17.693 17382-17382/? E/ActivityOnCreate: Content hasn't been set yet
2020-04-19 04:02:17.693 17382-17382/? E/ListInfo: Fragment list size is:0
2020-04-19 04:02:17.750 17382-17382/? E/ActivityOnCreate: Content has been set
2020-04-19 04:02:17.750 17382-17382/? E/ListInfo: Fragment list size is:1
2020-04-19 04:02:17.751 17382-17382/? E/ActivityInfo: Initiating MainActivity.onStart
2020-04-19 04:02:17.753 17382-17382/? E/DetachDetected: my_fragment Detached
2020-04-19 04:02:17.756 17382-17382/? E/ListInfo: Fragment list size is:1
2020-04-19 04:02:43.349 17382-17382/com.example.fragmentlife E/ActivityInfo: Initiating MainActivity.onDestroy
2020-04-19 04:02:43.350 17382-17382/com.example.fragmentlife E/DetachDetected: null Detached
2020-04-19 04:02:43.363 17382-17382/com.example.fragmentlife E/ActivityOnCreate: Content hasn't been set yet
2020-04-19 04:02:43.363 17382-17382/com.example.fragmentlife E/ListInfo: Fragment list size is:1
2020-04-19 04:02:43.370 17382-17382/com.example.fragmentlife E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

which begs the question why the fragment is still there and I think this actually causes this error (the actual reason I'm here):

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.fragmentlife.MyFragment did not create a view.
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3234)
 ...
```

a few lines before `FragmentManagerImpl`.java:3234, "`movetostate`" function checks if there was a state of this `fragment` and if there was it tries to get its view and inflate it but after detaching (I believe the view is destroyed at this point) it doesn't find a view and causes the error by doing:

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + fname + " did not create a view.");
```

Am I getting that Doc wrong?

**MyFragment class:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fgment, container, false);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/f_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="com.example.fragmentlife.MyFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="my_fragment"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and lastly fgment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1C39BB">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#DEDEDE"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note**: If i override activity's onPause() like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        List<Fragment> lf = mFragmentManager.getFragments();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        for(Fragment f : lf) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(f);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

I don't get that inflater error. Thought this might help.

Comment: You should not access `FragmentManager` after activitiy `super.onDestroy` since at that point fragment manager is destroyed as well.

Comment: yep. Thanks @Pawel. Edited the code for further clarification of the problem.